# Sharepoint 2007: Hiding wssuc:Welcome "Sign In" text, but not "Welcome" text

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint web page that users are required to sign in to use additional features. Different features require different sign ins, so I have a link to a page listing the various sign ins and their descriptions. Because of this link, I wish to hide the "Sign In" provided by wssuc:Welcome; however, I still wish to display the "Welcome" provided by wssuc:Welcome after the user has signed in.

I've researched this and arrived at 2 possible solutions:

1. Hide the "Sign In" using CSS in my code similar to this:

[CSS code added to master page]

```
   .myWelcomeMenu {
        display:none;
     }
```

[modified code in master]

```
<div class=”myWelcomeMenu”>
    <wssuc:Welcome id=”IdWelcome” runat=”server” EnableViewState=”false”>
    </wssuc:Welcome>
</div>
```

The problem with this is it will also hide the "Welcome" message.

1. Modify welcome.ascx, but this affects other sites on the server.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
George

Comment: Now I'm thinking, make a copy of Welcome.aspx, modify it to my needs, then have my sight refer to it, instead of Welcome.aspx. Then other sites will remain unaffected. Comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here:

**Hide the “Sign in” link in the client web browser for anonymous users**

http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2008/10/hide-sign-in-link-anonymous-users.html